# Toggle icon upon browser action click

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension, browser-action

How can I toggle my extension icon on browser action onclick?

**manifest.json**

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Toggle Icon",
  "description": "Toggle browser action Icon",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com/",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/message-48.png"
  },


  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/off.svg",
    "default_title": "ON"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

**background.js**

```
browser.browserAction.setIcon({
  path: {
    19: "icons/on.svg",
    38: "icons/on.svg"
  }
});
```

> [image: off.svg] - off.svg 
> [image: on.svg] - on.svg

Now the above code will automatically toggle the icon from 'off.svg' to 'on.svg' as soon as I load my extension to the browser. How can I setup the same thing on browser-action icon click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
let isEnabled = true
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    isEnabled = !isEnabled
    if (isEnabled) {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon({
            path: {
                19: "icons/on.svg",
                38: "icons/on.svg"
            }
        });
    } else {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon({
            path: {
                19: "icons/off.svg",
                38: "icons/off.svg"
            }
        });
    }
})
```

(untested)

Please note that by using the browser action as a toggle, you can't have a browser action popup anymore. In case you need such a popup, consider placing a toggle button into the popup.

Comment: It Worked. !! :) Also thanks for sharing knowledge regarding browser action popup.